# Apply ResponseText and put it as inputstream

Tags: android, http, encryption, httpresponse

I just need to decrypt response from httpresponse by the response is png picture so i did:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(tileURLString);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", String.valueOf(ValueX)));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

and if I get response by

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity == null) {
    Log.i("Error","No content download");
}

InputStream in = entity.getContent();
```

this is work. but i need to get this output as string to decrypt by use xor so all i did is:

```
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseText.getBytes());
```

PS. this still not decrypt just normal inputstream but didn't work. I googled for a day. Help me please. if this work i'll go to next step (decrypt).
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: or i use this method
Convert InputStream to string by

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Then i use this to convert back to inputstream but it also didn't work.

```
    public InputStream convertStringToStream(String text)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for answer is in this page

[Android byte array to string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493864/android-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array/10494496#10494496)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseText.getBytes());
```

changed to

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: if i use `getEntity().getContent()` how can i adapt the response before make it into inputstream?